# Python library installed for version 2.6 instead of 2.7

Tags: python, centos, yum

I have a CentOS and I needed to install the Mysql-python library and I did it with yum install MySQL-python. The problem is that now it is installed for python2.6 and not for python2.7 that is the one that I need to use.
The library works with python 2.6 but is not recognized by python2.7
How can I fix it??

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming this is CentOS 6? How did you install python 2.7? CentOS 6 only has python 2.6 in the system repositories (which is why the CentOS package for the library is available for that version). You will likely need to build that library yourself (or install it via whatever method got you python 2.7 in the first place) for this to work.

Comment: @EtanReisner I installed python2.7 with yum install python27. There are some imports in my code that only works with python27 thats why I need taht version.

Comment: Ah, that's an SCL package. I haven't dealt with SCL yet. It looks like there is a python27-MySQL-python package you should be able to install.

Comment: @EtanReisner I just found this one and it is for 64bits :/ http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/25204022/dir/centos_6/com/python27-MySQL-python-1.2.3-9.el6.centos.alt.x86_64.rpm.html  I really need to use python 2.7

Comment: Don't go find it. Just install it. `yum install python27-MySQL-python`. It should already be available to you from whatever repository gave you your python27 SCL RPM.

Comment: I did yum update and yum upgrade and then `yum install python27-MySQL-python` but `No package python27-MySQL-python available.` :/ :/ :/

Comment: What repositories do you have configured in yum?

Comment: Its a Amazon server: `amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                      
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                               
rpmforge `

Comment: What does `rpm -q --qf "%{n}-%{v}-%{r}.%{arch}\n" python27` output?

Comment: @EtanReisner python27-2.7.5-11.32.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: That isn't SCL then. That is something Amazon is providing (and doesn't match what I can find in SCL). You are going to need to ask Amazon why they don't provide the matching MySQL package for that version of python I think... or build it yourself.